# How do I solve the Authentication failure by Mesos

Tags: mesos

I have get the script file from https://github.com/nmilford/rpm-mesos/blob/master/mesos-master and I start to execute

> service mesos-master start

end up I got this

> Starting Mesos Master daemon (mesos-master):
>
> Password:
>
> su: Authentication failure

How do I start my mesos-master?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Mesos authentication failure. It is a failure to run `su $mesosUser`, when `$mesosUser` may not even be set. This repo is very old, so I would recommend looking for a newer rpm. If you don't need to build it yourself, you can download one from http://mesosphere.com/downloads/details/index.html#apache-mesos